# Построение простого динамического сайта на PHP

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Вопрос: как построить простую CMS ??? Главное что бы она взаимодействовала с БД и можно было генерировать страницы через БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Построение простого динамического
     сайта на PHP](http://pawno-info.ru/threads/28793-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-PHP)
- [Построение простого динамического
     сайта на PHP](http://acvarif.info/wbsphp.html)
- [Построение простого динамического
     сайта на PHP](http://biznesguide.ru/coding/65.html)